# Handling $_POST, $_GET data if a condition fails

Tags: php

I have a form that submits a few fields using `method="POST"`

If a condition were not met in the script that processes the request, should I destroy the `POST` data using `UNSET` or something like that, or should I just leave it there.

What happens to this data? Does PHP destroy it?

Example:

```
$a = 1;


if(isset($_POST['a'],$_POST['b'],$_POST['c'],$_POST['d'],$_POST['e'])) {

    if($a == 1) {
        echo 'Success'; // Do something with the data

    } else {
        // Should the above `POST` data be left as is, or should it be UNSET or...
    }

} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
```

Comment: I would leave `$_POST` and `$_GET` alone unless you have a really good reason to change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request a page, php processes the php script from line 1 to the end. After that, all variables, objects, and everything else is just vanished like it wasn't there.

> should I destroy the POST data using UNSET or something like that

No, You don't have to since it magically vanishes as if it was never there when php reaches the end of the page.
`$_POST` is just like any other variable. Nothing special about it except you don't have to created it manually. It is just destroyed at the end of the script automatically just like other variables

---

The only thing that is saved is

1. `session data` (usually in a file on the server) objects
2. `cookies` (as a file in your browser)

Answer (score 0):

**You could just leave as it is**. When you navigate to other page , these ( `$_POST` or `$_GET` ) data will **not be available** to the newly navigated page *whatsoever*. , so unsetting is pointless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to unset *$_POST* or *$_GET*?
This will not give you any advantages.

I suggest you to copy $_POST/$_GET array index that interest you to another variables and treat they in that new variable, or just set that new variable to *null* if they aren't necessary.

Also, in your code, you just need to check if $_POST indexes are set if your `$a == 1` condition is true, otherwise you are just spending processing time and memory.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to destroy $_GET or $_POST global variables. They will be automatically destroyed when php finishes its execution.